# I encountered an error. For 1 second a blue-screen appears and then my system shutdowns in windows-7

Tags: windows-7, windows-error-reporting

This was the error message I got when I restarted windows-7.
[image]

There was a lot of things written on that blue screen.

A similar [screen-shot](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/_tbHfaj1A058/SpTwd2CBuaI/AAAAAAAAHSI/a8ms5Ow54LU/s1600-h/DSC01703.JPG)

The heading on that blue screen was "Error Detected".

What was this ? How can I prevent this ?

According to Nick-G 's answer, the website gave following output,

**EDIT-1 :**

Show DivPrimary Analysis

```
Crash Dump Analysis provided by OSR Open Systems Resources, Inc. (http://www.osr.com)
Online Crash Dump Analysis Service
See http://www.osronline.com for more information
Windows 7 Kernel Version 7601 (Service Pack 1) MP (2 procs) Free x86 compatible
Product: WinNt, suite: TerminalServer SingleUserTS
Built by: 7601.18247.x86fre.win7sp1_gdr.130828-1532
Machine Name:
Kernel base = 0x82c0a000 PsLoadedModuleList = 0x82d534d0
Debug session time: Thu Apr 24 12:58:09.915 2014 (UTC - 4:00)
System Uptime: 0 days 1:58:40.024
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL (a)
An attempt was made to access a pageable (or completely invalid) address at an
interrupt request level (IRQL) that is too high.  This is usually
caused by drivers using improper addresses.
If a kernel debugger is available get the stack backtrace.
Arguments:
Arg1: 5c0d6dd0, memory referenced
Arg2: 00000002, IRQL
Arg3: 00000000, bitfield :
    bit 0 : value 0 = read operation, 1 = write operation
    bit 3 : value 0 = not an execute operation, 1 = execute operation (only on chips which support this level of status)
Arg4: 82c42e63, address which referenced memory

Debugging Details:
------------------

TRIAGER: Could not open triage file : e:\dump_analysis\program\triage\modclass.ini, error 2

READ_ADDRESS: GetPointerFromAddress: unable to read from 82d7384c
Unable to read MiSystemVaType memory at 82d52e20
 5c0d6dd0 

CURRENT_IRQL:  2

FAULTING_IP: 
nt!memcpy+33
82c42e63 f3a5            rep movs dword ptr es:[edi],dword ptr [esi]

CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN7_DRIVER_FAULT

BUGCHECK_STR:  0xA

PROCESS_NAME:  System

TRAP_FRAME:  8a72f2e0 -- (.trap 0xffffffff8a72f2e0)
ErrCode = 00000000
eax=5c0d6e2d ebx=8a72f3a4 ecx=00000017 edx=00000001 esi=5c0d6dd0 edi=86cd09c0
eip=82c42e63 esp=8a72f354 ebp=8a72f35c iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz ac pe nc
cs=0008  ss=0010  ds=0023  es=0023  fs=0030  gs=0000             efl=00010216
nt!memcpy+0x33:
82c42e63 f3a5            rep movs dword ptr es:[edi],dword ptr [esi]
Resetting default scope

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from 82c42e63 to 82c4ab7f

STACK_TEXT:  
8a72f2e0 82c42e63 badb0d00 00000001 00000000 nt!KiTrap0E+0x1b3
8a72f35c 8d39caf6 86cd09c0 5c0d6dd0 0000005d nt!memcpy+0x33
8a72f3a4 8d341c69 b2ac4c20 86b069e8 00000c20 afd!AfdBReceiveEventHandler+0x1af
8a72f484 88a6516d 87bd4458 8a72f4f0 8a72f5e4 tdx!TdxEventReceiveConnection+0x23f
8a72f514 88a616e0 85b16154 0000df67 8a72f5e4 tcpip!TcpIndicateData+0x203
8a72f5a8 88a635c7 c1c20270 c1c20368 8a72f5e4 tcpip!TcpDeliverDataToClient+0x2fa
8a72f5fc 88a96fe4 c1c20270 c1c20368 86ca9b38 tcpip!TcpDeliverReceive+0x96
8a72f694 88a95559 85afadb0 c1c20270 8a72f6bc tcpip!TcpTcbCarefulDatagram+0x1761
8a72f700 88a78a08 85afadb0 c1c20270 0072f774 tcpip!TcpTcbReceive+0x22d
8a72f768 88a7923a 85acd108 85af1000 00000000 tcpip!TcpMatchReceive+0x237
8a72f7b8 88a7927b 85afadb0 85af1000 000038cc tcpip!TcpPreValidatedReceive+0x293
8a72f7d4 88a7358f 85afadb0 85af1000 8a72f810 tcpip!TcpReceive+0x2d
8a72f7e4 88a7b7e4 8a72f7f8 c000023e 00000000 tcpip!TcpNlClientReceiveDatagrams+0x12
8a72f810 88a7b126 88af8198 8a72f864 c000023e tcpip!IppDeliverListToProtocol+0x49
8a72f830 88a794e8 88af7fa8 00000006 8a72f864 tcpip!IppProcessDeliverList+0x2a
8a72f888 88a7afcf 88af7fa8 00000006 00000000 tcpip!IppReceiveHeaderBatch+0x1fb
8a72f91c 88a894e5 860a5828 00000000 85af0d00 tcpip!IpFlcReceivePackets+0xbe5
8a72f998 88a83a6d 860e7468 86ca9b38 00000000 tcpip!FlpReceiveNonPreValidatedNetBufferListChain+0x746
8a72f9cc 82c92ac3 86ca9b38 aa2f8412 00000000 tcpip!FlReceiveNetBufferListChainCalloutRoutine+0x11e
8a72fa34 88a83bdb 88a8394f 8a72fa5c 00000000 nt!KeExpandKernelStackAndCalloutEx+0x132
8a72fa70 8890d18d 860e7400 86ca9b01 00000000 tcpip!FlReceiveNetBufferListChain+0x7c
8a72faa8 888fb5be 860a2918 86ca9b38 00000000 ndis!ndisMIndicateNetBufferListsToOpen+0x188
8a72fad0 888fb4b2 00000000 86ca9b38 85ee00e0 ndis!ndisIndicateSortedNetBufferLists+0x4a
8a72fc4c 888a6c2d 85ee00e0 00000000 00000000 ndis!ndisMDispatchReceiveNetBufferLists+0x129
8a72fc68 888fb553 85ee00e0 86ca9b38 00000000 ndis!ndisMTopReceiveNetBufferLists+0x2d
8a72fc90 888a6c88 85ee00e0 86ca9b38 00000000 ndis!ndisMIndicateReceiveNetBufferListsInternal+0x62
8a72fcb8 909766b7 85ee00e0 86ca9b38 00000000 ndis!NdisMIndicateReceiveNetBufferLists+0x52
8a72fcd8 90971730 860dee18 86ca9b38 860dee18 tunnel!TeredoWfpIndicationWorker+0xa9
8a72fcec 82e1e625 860dee18 90982a68 84d8f798 tunnel!LwWorker+0x12
8a72fd00 82c8714b b3b78008 00000000 84d8f798 nt!IopProcessWorkItem+0x23
8a72fd50 82e1313d 00000001 aa2f83b6 00000000 nt!ExpWorkerThread+0x10d
8a72fd90 82cba559 82c8703e 00000001 00000000 nt!PspSystemThreadStartup+0x9e
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 nt!KiThreadStartup+0x19


STACK_COMMAND:  kb

FOLLOWUP_IP: 
tdx!TdxEventReceiveConnection+23f
8d341c69 8bd8            mov     ebx,eax

SYMBOL_STACK_INDEX:  3

SYMBOL_NAME:  tdx!TdxEventReceiveConnection+23f

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

MODULE_NAME: tdx

IMAGE_NAME:  tdx.sys

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  4ce78935

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  0xA_tdx!TdxEventReceiveConnection+23f

BUCKET_ID:  0xA_tdx!TdxEventReceiveConnection+23f

Followup: MachineOwner
---------
```

Comment: So, it looks like the error was due to something related to your network card.   IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL (a) means that a device tried to access a address in memory that either did not contain the data it expected, or was not allocated to be used by the problem device.  The error occurred in tdx.sys (a Microsoft networking file named the TDI Translation Driver)
The stack trace shows that TCP/IP was also running just prior to the crash (more networking stuff).

Comment: WHY is everyone saying `DIFFERENT PROBLEMS` ?

Answer (score 0):

Upload the minidump file it mentions (the latest one) to this site: http://www.osronline.com/page.cfm?name=analyze

..and it should give you some clues as to what's causing the blue screen errors.

Comment: I uploaded the `042414-14164-01.dmp` file now the website says something long

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend downloading Blue Screen Dump from Nirsoft

http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/blue_screen_view.html

it does a great job of figuring out the cause of the BSOD and pointing you in the right direction to get it fixed.   Keep in mind, Windows will occasionally blue screen - I would not worry about it too much unless it happens more than once.

Comment: The blue screen happened once, Will it happen another time?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect from the log you've posted that you have a memory problem (faulty RAM). I would run the [Microsoft memory tool](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows7/diagnosing-memory-problems-on-your-computer) or Memtest86 to check that your RAM is OK (this will take several hours and ideally needs to be left to run overnight so it has time to do multiple passes.

Comment: There is `2GB ram` and `2.9 GHz intel pentium` processor in my PC, How much time can the check take?

Comment: Try it and see... There's no way for anyone to know in advance. Having read the log in more detail though, I think @magicandre1981's answer is most likely right.

Answer (score 0):

The Tunnel.sys driver seams to be the cause.

Disable the [Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-interface 6to4 Adapter](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/richin/archive/2010/11/26/how-to-disable-teredo-tunneling-pseudo-interface-6to4-adapter.aspx) with the command from the picture to fix the issue.

[image]